# I have a HTML & CSS layout issue

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with the layout of my HTML & CSS site.

There are meant to be 4 boxes under the top image, At the moment there are only 3. I would like them to be spread out evenly across the page. The one that isn't visible is history of gaming, I believe that for some reason it is underneath the image...

here is the code:

```css
.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('http://i118.photobucket.com/albums/o117/Shawnthebro/bandicam2014-03-2311-20-03-210_zpse7f7712f.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  height: 350px;
  display: block;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 350px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
.page ul {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-left: 75px;
  .page ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .page a {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding-left: 70px;
    div.img {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      width: 275px;
    }
    div.img:hover {
      border: 1px solid #777;
    }
    div.img img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    div.desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <title>Gaming T,N & B</title>
  <style>
    div.img {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      width: 275px;
    }
    div.img:hover {
      border: 1px solid #777;
    }
    div.img img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    div.desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Gaming: Then, Now & Beyond</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">History of Gaming</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/atari.html">Atari</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Other Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/future.html">Future</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="history.png">
      <img src="history.png" alt="The History of Gaming" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>What is gaming?</li>
          <li>Pong</li>
          <li>Technology Boom</li>
        </ul>
        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn more about the history of gaming</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="atari.jpg">
      <img src="atari.jpg" alt="Atari" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <div>
        <h3>Atari</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>40 years of fun</li>
          <li>Who is Nolan Bushnell</li>
          <li>Bought & Sold</li>
        </ul>
        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/atari.html">Learn more about Atari</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="xbox_ps1.jpg">
      <img src="xbox_ps1.jpg" alt="Other Games" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <div>
        <h3>Other Games</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>PC</li>
          <li>Xbox</li>
          <li>PlayStation</li>
        </ul>
        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Learn more about other games</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="future_ocu.jpg">
      <img src="future_ocu.jpg" alt="Future Gaming" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
      <div>
        <h3>Future</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Gaming in society</li>
          <li>Who is driving who?</li>
          <li>CrowdFunding</li>
        </ul>
        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/future.html">Learn about future gaming</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <iframe width="1150" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/X1tBEKFYKJg?autoplay=1" style="border:5px dotted red">
  </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Many Thanks

Adam

Comment: I think you'd benefit greatly by scrapping your existing markup and move to using Twitters Bootstrap to build your page.  Bootstrap works using a flexible grid system which would be perfect for this site.  Your banner would use a 12 column div (100% width) and each of your 4 boxes would be a 3 column width on the bootstrap grid.   You can then specify different behaviour for smaller resolutions, i.e `.col-sm-6` will make each box 50% of the screen on a small device, giving the appearance of 2 boxes next to eachother with 2 immediately underneath: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ CSS guide here

Comment: Just looking at your code, it seems like you need to move the `desc` div before your first `img` div. That's why you only see the three down below. You also don't need to prefix every class with the `div` selector. Just the classes work great.

Comment: I second @Alex's suggestion of starting with Bootstrap rather than your existing code.

Comment: Depends what you want in terms of backwards compatibility / browser support. If you must support pre-IE11 consider a framework such as foundation or bootstrap. If you can do without that support, feel free to use flexbox to lay things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a div class "img" for the three boxes below the jumbotron. each has a div class "desc" inside it. for the history of gaming, you need to nest the "desc" class div inside the "img" class div, as such:

```
<div class="img">
            <a target="_blank" href="history.png">
                <img src="history.png" alt="The History of Gaming" width="300" height="200">
                    </a>

            <div class="desc">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>What is gaming?</li>
                            <li>Pong</li>
                            <li>Technology Boom</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p><a href="">Learn more about the history of gaming</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

what you posted has the desc class div outside the first img class div.

Answer (score 1):

> Bootstrap Example

Someone suggested to use bootstrap, so I created a simple example for you. I hope it is close to what you are looking for.

```css
body {height 100%;
 background:
  url("http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Rough-horizonal-lines-Grey-Seamless-Pattern-For-Website-Background.jpg");
}

.navbar {
 margin: 0;
}

div.container {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

div.container>div.jumbotron {
 color: white;
 background-image:
  url('http://i118.photobucket.com/albums/o117/Shawnthebro/bandicam2014-03-2311-20-03-210_zpse7f7712f.jpg');
 text-shadow: black 2px 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
      data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
      aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
       class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
       class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
     id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">History of Gaming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Atari</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Future</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
   <h1>Gaming: Then, Now & Beyond</h1>
   <p>Some extra text</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <article class="container">
  <section class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
     <img
      src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/28000000/randomised-random-28065165-1024-819.jpg"
      alt="...">
     <div class="caption">
      <h3>Atari</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>40 years of fun</li>
       <li>Who is Nolan Bushnell</li>
       <li>Bought & Sold</li>
      </ul>
      <p>
       <a
        href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn
        more about the history of gaming</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
     <img
      src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/28000000/randomised-random-28065165-1024-819.jpg"
      alt="...">
     <div class="caption">
      <h3>Other Games</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>PC</li>
       <li>Xbox</li>
       <li>PlayStation</li>
      </ul>
      <p>
       <a
        href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Learn
        more about other games</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
     <img
      src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/28000000/randomised-random-28065165-1024-819.jpg"
      alt="...">
     <div class="caption">
      <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>What is gaming?</li>
       <li>Pong</li>
       <li>Technology Boom</li>
      </ul>
      <p>
       <a
        href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn
        more about the history of gaming</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

  <section class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">YouTube Video</div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <iframe width="1150" height="315"
      src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/X1tBEKFYKJg?autoplay=0">
     </iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

 </article>
 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
 <script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
  crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
<title>Gaming T,N & B</title>



<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
    crossorigin="anonymous">


<style>
body {height 100%;
    background:
        url("http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Rough-horizonal-lines-Grey-Seamless-Pattern-For-Website-Background.jpg");
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0;
}

div.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

div.container>div.jumbotron {
    color: white;
    background-image:
        url('http://i118.photobucket.com/albums/o117/Shawnthebro/bandicam2014-03-2311-20-03-210_zpse7f7712f.jpg');
    text-shadow: black 2px 2px 8px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some Title</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                    id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">History of Gaming</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Atari</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other Games</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Future</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Gaming: Then, Now & Beyond</h1>
            <p>Some extra text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <article class="container">
        <section class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/28000000/randomised-random-28065165-1024-819.jpg"
                        alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Atari</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>40 years of fun</li>
                            <li>Who is Nolan Bushnell</li>
                            <li>Bought & Sold</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>
                            <a
                                href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn
                                more about the history of gaming</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/28000000/randomised-random-28065165-1024-819.jpg"
                        alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Other Games</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>PC</li>
                            <li>Xbox</li>
                            <li>PlayStation</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>
                            <a
                                href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Learn
                                more about other games</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img
                        src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/28000000/randomised-random-28065165-1024-819.jpg"
                        alt="...">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>What is gaming?</li>
                            <li>Pong</li>
                            <li>Technology Boom</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>
                            <a
                                href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn
                                more about the history of gaming</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">YouTube Video</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe width="1150" height="315"
                        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/X1tBEKFYKJg?autoplay=0">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    </article>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*My first answer. I'm quite inexperienced at answering questions*
I'm not sure if this is intended, but there are no closing curly brackets for `.page a`
 `.page a {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding-left: 70px;
    div.img {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      width: 275px;
    }`
Also, 
`<div class="desc">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>What is gaming?</li>
          <li>Pong</li>
          <li>Technology Boom</li>
        </ul>
        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn more about the history of gaming</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
should be in the same `<div>` as the image. Something like this: 
`<div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="history.png">
      <img src="history.png" alt="The History of Gaming" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>What is gaming?</li>
          <li>Pong</li>
          <li>Technology Boom</li>
        </ul>
        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn more about the history of gaming</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>`
This aligns the four boxes (add padding to move them down afterwards if you want)
I edited it because I think there was a badge for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table{
  TABLE-LAYOUT:FIXED;
    border:solid;
  width:100%;
}
td{
  padding:5px;
  width:25%;
  border:solid grey
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>veryveryverylongtest</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```